# Get values but don't print it in the console

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a script with a function where inside I have something like this

```
Get-SPFeature ... bla bla bla
```

now I use the result of this cmd to do a check and I don't want print the result of this cmd on my console.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$result = Get-SPFeature ... bla bla bla` doesn't capture the output, then the command writes to other streams than STDOUT. Try redirecting all streams:

```
$result = Get-SPFeature ... bla bla bla *>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can suppress the output of a function by giving it to Out-Null

```
Get-SPFeature ... bla bla bla | Out-Null
```

Or by assigning to variable

```
$Result = Get-SPFeature ... bla bla bla
```

Comment: And by assigning to `$null` you get the same result as with `Out-Null`, except you don't have to make up a dummy variable name if you don't need the result.

Comment: I did with the variable but I got the same result